# VS Code Python get Peak Area and Retention Time

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get some information out of my chromatographic GC data.

My Problem: So I'm hoping that somebody could help me write a VS code in python for the analysis of my chromatogram. I want a code that in the end gives me a list of numbered peaks with the retention time and peak area for each peak.I'm able to display the data in vs code, but I want to get the retention time of the peaks and the area for each peak. Does anybody already have a code for this problem or knows how to solve it?

I'm using Python as language and my files are .csv

I have a code for R if that helps.
R also only integrates the first peak and only gives the first peak's retention time.

Thank you in advance!!

```
rm(list=ls())
setwd("xxx")


library(OrgMassSpecR)
library(pracma)
library(colorspace)
library(chromatographR)
library(chromConverter)
library(dplyr)
library(farver)
library(grid)
library(gridGraphics)
library(lambda.r)
library(lambdr)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(vctrs)
library(viridisLite)


D <- read.csv("xxx.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"",
              dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "",)


x <- seq(0,1, len=nrow(D)) 
autoCompress = 1.0

#findpeaks(x, nups = 3, ndowns = 4, zero = "0", peakpat = NULL, minpeakheight = -Inf, minpeakdistance = 1, threshold = 100, npeaks = 10, sortstr = FALSE)


findpeaks(
  x,
  nups = 1,
  ndowns = 1,
  zero = "0",
  peakpat = NULL,
  minpeakheight = -Inf,
  minpeakdistance = 1,
  npeaks = 0,
  sortstr = FALSE,
)



y <- DrawChromatogram(D$RT,D$TIC,range=list(start="0",stop="Inf"), 
                      options(scipen = 999),
                      xlab = "retention time (sec)", 
                      ylab = "intensity", 
                      main = "xxx",
)

print.data.frame(y)

text(y$retentionTime +48 , y$apexIntensity , 
     labels = paste("RT = " ,round(y$retentionTime, digits = 3),
                    ", Area = " ,round(y$peakArea), sep = ""), cex = 0.9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, you can use libraries like **Pandas** for data manipulation and **Matplotlib** for visualization. Here is a simple example code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

# Read CSV file
file_path = "xxx.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)

# Plot chromatogram
plt.plot(data['Retention Time'], data['Intensity'])
plt.xlabel('Retention Time (sec)')
plt.ylabel('Intensity')
plt.title('Chromatogram')
plt.show()

# Find peaks using scipy's find_peaks
peaks, _ = find_peaks(data['Intensity'], height=0)

# Extract peak information
peak_info = pd.DataFrame({
    'Peak Number': range(1, len(peaks) + 1),
    'Retention Time': data['Retention Time'][peaks],
    'Peak Area': data['Intensity'][peaks],
})

# Display peak information
print(peak_info)
```

Comment: Glad my answer was helpful to you, you can change the status of the answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.